# Are previously invited Trello users automatically added to a new invite board?

Tags: trello, notifications

When I add a member to a [Trello](https://trello.com/) board, the UI pops up a list of possible choices. This list includes people who have accepted the invitation I have previously sent for other Trello boards.

If I choose a user from this list, do they get an invitation email or are they just automatically added to the board without waiting for a response from an invitation email?

Answer (score 4):

If the user is in the **same organization as you** and the **board is part of that organization**, you can automatically add them to the board:

1. Click the `Add Members` button and they will be listed under the
   `current members` section.
2. Click a user and select `Add to board`.
3. They will get added immediately, without going through the email / accept process.

There's more information about it on our blog: [Improving Organizations: Adding Members and Self-Join](http://blog.trello.com/improving-organizations-adding-members-and-self-join/)

If they are **not in the same organization**, you will have to go through the normal invite process.

Answer (score 0):

They are **still** sent an invitation email to join your new board, even if you've *already* asked them to join you on a *different* board.

Before they can join the new board, they will have to accept the invite. They are **not automatically added**.